# AWS Cloudfront cache invalidation paths usage

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cache-invalidation

I am using **s3 bucket** as origin in **cloudfront** to cache and host my **reactjs** website.

After every deployment on s3 i want to **invalidate** the cache of my cloudfront distribution so that the user can get the latest build deployed..

Moreover, while reading the [pricing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#PayingForInvalidation) of cloudfront invalidation, i want to make sure i don't exceed the free tier which is **1000 paths** per month. Plus we don't have more then 10 or 20 deployments to production in a month.. and each deployment has around 500 files in directories:

[image]

So my question is:   if i use `"/*"` as a invalidation query would it be considered as a **1 path** ? or it would be **500 paths** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is the same [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#PayingForInvalidation) you provided in your question. Your question is whether wildcard is considered as 1 path or multiple part, so here is the screenshot for the same :

[image]

**EDIT :**   For your confirmation, you can find the number of invalidations for a period of time by filtering the "Cost & Usage Report" (AWS console) by service="CloudFront" and usageType="Invalidations".

Hope this answers your question. Feel free to comment for any question.

Comment: have you tried invalidate root folder /*,  was it considered single path ?

Comment: Yes, I have used root folder wildcard, but didn't check myself for single path and relied on the docs I put in answer.  For your confirmation, you can find the number of invalidations for a period of time by filtering the "Cost & Usage Report" (AWS console) by service="CloudFront" and usageType="Invalidations".

Comment: I tried as you informed for checking the usage after creating a `/*`  **invalidation**,  downloading the csv file i  found that is `UsageValue: 1` .  so i hope it means paths is also 1 ... thanks  :D

Comment: I edited original answer with steps to check usage. Please accept the answer if you think this helped you.

Comment: its still not sure that usage 1 means 1 path or 500 paths, i have created support ticket at aws.. once verified will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The below excerpt which clarifies regarding the paths:

> The charge to submit an invalidation path is the same regardless of
> the number of files you're invalidating: a single file
> `(/images/logo.jpg)` or all of the files that are associated with a
> distribution `(/*)`. For more information, see [Amazon CloudFront
> Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/).

The text is taken from docs mentioned in the link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects-paths

which means that the `"/*"` is a single path.